# How can i learn Stored Procedure and Trigger?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to learn quickly writing Stored Procedure and Trigger?

Can you suggest any link, eBook, etc?

Comment: I suggest this link: http://www.google.com

Comment: You need to specify which server you are talking about since most are using different dialects of SQL. This contains ebooks on SQL http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/203968

Comment: Hi Dear @Soner Gönül. is there any possibity to be in touch with you. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start here.  These are mostly for Sql Server:

[Introduction to Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)
[Introduction to Stored Procedures](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/stored_procedures_basics_p1.aspx)
[Stored Procedures on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214299.aspx)
[Stored procedure and trigger execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-aus/library/ms190201.aspx)
[Comparing Stored Procedures and Triggers](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/answer/SQL-Server-trigger-vs-stored-procedure-to-receive-data-notification)
[Comparing Stored Procedures Views and Triggers](http://www.paragoncorporation.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?ArticleID=28)

Answer (score 1):

They are not hard as you think.

Examine some examples and read some tutorial.

[Oracle Simple Trigger and Stored Procedure tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/win.920/a97248/ch3.htm)

[Tetikleyiciler](http://vtlab.cs.hacettepe.edu.tr/sunumlar/ch05-plsql.pdf)