# Oracle triggers and stored procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, web-applications, stored-procedures, triggers

I need to make for my webApp a trigger to execute a stored procedure on Oracle. But i'm very new to Oracle and I'm still getting the hang of it. I can make a simple Trigger with a sequence to auto-increment a value from a table, but that's it.

Is there any good tutorials and examples available on this specific subject? I tried searching here, but i have only found a very generic question: [How can i learn Stored Procedure and Trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967098/how-can-i-learn-stored-procedure-and-trigger/4526692). But i can be more specific: I need this trigger to run a stored procedure that generates a new code for my user, adding data to this code. The procedure is done, i just don't know how to use it in a trigger, pass the parameters, and how to insert/update values from the oracle trigger itself.

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your function to generate the code is named `f_generate_code()` and your table is named `foobar` and the column that should be populated is name `code` you'd do it like this:

```
create or replace trigger trg_update_code
  before insert or update on foobar
  for each row
begin
  :new.code := f_generate_code();
end;
/
```

Comment: Good one. Do you happen to know where i can get more info on the subject?

Comment: @HugoRocha: the manual is a good start: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/toc.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/toc.htm